# Flurl Http GetAsync() - How to verify response text?

Tags: c#, .net, flurl

I am struggeling with `Flurl.Http` to verify the response text of a `GetAsync()` request.
My code:

```
var resp = await "https://.../version"
                .GetAsync();

Assert.Equal(200, resp.StatusCode);
Assert.Equal("1.0.0.0", resp.WhatDoIHaveToDoHere?);
```

Someone here who knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're expecting `1.0.0.0` to be in the *body* of the response? If so, this should do it:

```
Assert.Equal("1.0.0.0", await resp.GetStringAsync());
```